# Backtracking: 8 Bishops to occupy whole board

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I'm stuck with writing this backtracking algorithm down. Problem: 8 bishops have to cover whole chessboard. All it have to do is place 4 bishops on white chessboard spaces, check if it occupies 32 spaces. If it does, move 4 new bishops to the left, so they stand on black spaces and the problem is solved. If it doesn't - use backtrack to place bishops somewhere else. The problem is, I just can't write the backtrack down - it seems too complex for me.

Here's what I've done:

```
void findBishops(){
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){ //get row
        int j;
        if (i%2==1) j=1; //2n+1 row has second white space, so we skip the first black space
        else j=0;
        for (; j<N; j+=2){ //get column
            //put into array those bishop coordinates and repeat 3 more times to get all 4 bishops.
            isFull(board, array); //give coordinates and check if all white spaces are occupied
            //if not - backtrack
            }
    }
}

bool isFull(int  board[][N], array[]){
   putIntoBoard(board, array[0], array[1]);
   putIntoBoard(board, array[2], array[3]);
   putIntoBoard(board, array[4], array[5]);
   putIntoBoard(board, array[6], array[7]);

    int i,j;
    int count=0;
    for (i=0; i<=7; i++){

        if (i%2==1) j=1;
        else j=0;

        for (; j<=7; j+=2){
            if (board[i][j]==1) count++;
        }
    }
    if (count==32){
        clean(board); 
        return true;
    }else{  
        clean(board);
        return false;
    }
}

void putIntoBoard(int board[][N], int a, int b){ //fills diagonal white spaces on board with 1's
    int i=a,j=b;
    board[i][j]=1;

    while(i>0 && (j<7) )/*to Up right*/{
        i--;
        j++;
        board[i][j]=1;
    }
    i=a;
    j=b;
    while(j>0 && i>0) /*to Up left*/{
        i--;
        j--;
        board[i][j]=1;

    }
    i=a;
    j=b;
    while(i<7&& j<7) /*to bottom right*/{
        i++;
        j++;
        board[i][j]=1;

    }
    i=a;
    j=b;

    while(i<7 && j>0) /*to bottom left*/{

        i++;
        j--;
        board[i][j]=1;
    }


}
```

Here's the `main function`:

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 8
using namespace std;
void print(int board[][N]);
void putIntoBoard(int a, int b, int board[][N]);
bool isFull(int  board[][N], array[]);   
void clean(int board[][N]);

int main()
{
    int board [N][N]= {0};
    int count= 0;

    findBishops();

    cout<<"Counted possibilites: "<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's just a prototype, If you have something better, please share, I'll gladly take all reviews.

EDIT: I've forgot to include my other algoritm used a few days ago, but it has no recursion nor backtracking, here it is:

```
int main()
{
    int board [N][N]= {0};
    int count= 0;



    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int j;
        if (i%2==1) j=1;
        else j=0;
        for (; j<N; j+=2)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
            {
                int n;
                if (k%2==1) n=1;
                else n=0;
                for (; n<N; n+=2)
                {

                    for (int l=0; l<N; l++)
                    {
                        int o;
                        if (l%2==1) o=1;
                        else o=0;
                        for (; o<N; o+=2)
                        {

                            for(int m=0; m<N; m++)
                            {
                                int p;
                                if (m%2==1) p=1;
                                else p=0;
                                for (; p<N; p+=2)
                                {

                                    if (isFull(board,i,j,k,n,l,o,m,p))
                                    {
                                        count++;
                                        cout<<"Board filled up with white spaces on: ("<<i<<","<<j<<"), "<<"("<<k<<","<<n<<"), "<<"("<<l<<","<<o<<"), "<<"("<<m<<","<<p<<"), "<<endl;
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Counted possibilities: "<<count<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for me the task is unclear. may be refine your problem description. should the bishops cover the entire field? the solution seems quite simple and obvious. why using backtracking? and from where does the knowledge come that to place 4 on white first, count covered area and then place black besides them? seems very artificial.

Comment: Yes, the 8 bishops have to cover whole chessboard. Our lecturer asked us to use backtracking.

Comment: yes i understand it as a training exercise but i would use a simple backtracking without so many prior knowledge like setting 4 bishops, count and then set black

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas I also have to admit it is not the best problem to show how backtracking works, since an obvious solution is to place the bishops on a1, a2, ..., a8 for example. Unless of course there are some other pieces on the board - in which case you better mention it in the question.

Comment: @Gassa: Actually, your "obvoius solution" is incorrect ;)

Comment: As for your code, you didn't provide a runnable example in your first code (no `main`), but a thing to note is that arrays in C++ are numbered from zero, but you chose to number `array` from 1 to 8, which may be treated inconsistently in the missing `main` function or other places.

Comment: There is no recursion in the supposedly recursive solution. It looks like you're trying to do too much in `isFull` - I think this will be much easier if you make `isFull` a predicate that doesn't modify the state of the board, but instead break down the problem further (generate - test - backtrack). (You don't seem entirely clear on what the backtracking step is - when you've exhausted the options for the fourth bishop, backtrack to the third, move it and try again, and so on.)

Comment: yes you have to put the bishop line in the middle of the field

Comment: @MikeMB Yeah, sorry! Still, some d1, d2, ..., d8 will do - this time I checked =)

Comment: @vlad_tepesch It's one of the solutions, but I have to find all of them. 
@Gassa sorry, my honest mistake in the array and I'll edit the post with `main`. Plus I've showed the program without recursion to the lecturer and he wanted me to change the algorithm to use backtracking solution. 

And please, if someone have some time, could you post your solution to this problem, because I'm getting anxious from this as I can't solve it four days straight.

Comment: Could you please provide an example, that at least compiles? It is hard to determine, which errors are in your actual code and which errors are just copy paste errors when you put it here.

Comment: @MikeMB here the code that compiles and runs perfectly: http://pastebin.com/0TWcYuVR Sorry it's not translated to english, but the code is the same as my previous one without recursion. I try to turn this code into recursion but with no luck.

Comment: Your code, even with the added main function, still does not resemble a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): `array` is not declared, there is no body for `clean`, signature of `isFull` is not valid C++, etc. If you included a code that one could just copy and run, the chances you get a satisfactory answer would increase significantly.

Answer (score 1):

For moving 4 bishops to black fields, simply *mirror* them relatively the vertical central axis. Or the horizontal one - the result will be the same. They will go to the black fields and they will threaten all black fields (if they threatened all white fields before mirroring).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I already know this situation. The problem is writing it down, which I struggle with.

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas You don't know how to set mirrored positions to points??? i=9-i; is enough.